# How to create a drupal view using sql

Tags: 7, views, database

Is there anyway for me to create a Drupal view from two sql queries and have two separate outputs. Here is the two SQL queries I want to create a view from:

SELECT f.delta      AS field_data_field_session_start_date_delta
     , f.entity_id  AS date_id_date_filter
     , f.delta      AS date_delta_date_filter
     , n.title      AS node_title
     , n.nid        AS nid
     , n.language   AS node_language
     , f.field_session_start_date_value AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date
     , f.field_session_start_date_value2 AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date2
     , 'node'       AS field_data_field_session_start_date_node_entity_type
  FROM `node` n
  JOIN `field_data_field_session_start_date` f
    ON f.entity_id = n.nid
   AND f.entity_type = 'node'
   AND f.deleted = '0'
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value >= NOW()
WHERE n.status = '1'
ORDER
    BY f.field_session_start_date_value ASC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0

SELECT f.delta      AS field_data_field_session_start_date_delta
     , f.entity_id  AS date_id_date_filter
     , f.delta      AS date_delta_date_filter
     , n.title      AS node_title
     , n.nid        AS nid
     , n.language   AS node_language
     , f.field_session_start_date_value AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date
     , f.field_session_start_date_value2 AS field_data_field_session_start_date_field_session_start_date2
     , 'node'       AS field_data_field_session_start_date_node_entity_type
  FROM `node` n
  JOIN `field_data_field_session_start_date` f
    ON f.entity_id = n.nid
   AND f.entity_type = 'node'
   AND f.deleted = '0'
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value <= NOW()
   AND f.field_session_start_date_value2 > NOW()
WHERE n.status = '1'
ORDER
    BY f.field_session_start_date_value ASC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0

Comment: Why cant you just use Views UI?

Comment: Views is a query builder. You already have a query built. What are you trying to do?

Comment: well basically I am  trying to create view that uses two sql queries and have two outputs (i will update the question)

Comment: Can you provide any context about what the larger goal is?

Comment: well basically these are two queries on a events one brings up events that are on currently and the other is to bring events that are yet to start and I want to create a view that has 3 total fields with priority to the output from the now query

Comment: example if there are two events on now display one event yet to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make 2 Views with your `LIMIT 3` clauses from the SQL you've provided using the Views UI.

Then make a custom block in a module. Use [views_get_view_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) ([see additional documentation and usage of views_get_view_result here](https://drupal.org/node/342132)) to call your 2 views programmatically from PHP code. Then in your block output content simply loop through upto 3 items in your *NOW* listing, then add any needed items from your *UPCOMING* listing if the max of 3 items hasn't been reached yet. [An example of how to make a block in code by Four Kitchens can be seen here](http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2012/07/18/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7). Taking their example your `hook_block_view` may look like below.

```
function custom_block_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
  case 'my_block' :
    $block['content'] = my_three_upcoming_events();
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function my_three_upcoming_events() {
  $output = '';
  $now_events = views_get_view_result('VIEWNAME_FOR_NOW_EVENTS_VIEW');
  $upcoming_events = views_get_view_result('VIEWNAME_FOR_UPCOMING_EVENTS_VIEW');
  $max_events = 3;
  // Make a big list of events now; upcoming events will be on the end of this list.
  $all_events = $now_events + $upcoming_events;

  for ($i=0,$z=$max_events;$i<$z;$i++) {
    $node = node_load($all_events[$i]['nid']);
    $output .= '<div>' . l($node->title, '/node/'.$node->nid) . '</div>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks tenken , to get this to work do I machine name of the two views, if I do what how do I get the machine name of the view.

Comment: when you create a View you give it a Name; there is an option to view/edit the machine name when creating a view. For an existing View, when you Edit the view the machine name is in the url: `/admin/structure/views/view/admin_faculty_listing/edit` ... here `admin_faculty_listing` is the view machine name.

Comment: Hi Tenken, I have added the necessary part of the code the link example. I then added in the code above and changed the view names correctly, but the new block doesnt come up on the block listing.

Comment: I am not familar with views_get_view_result as I am relatively new to drupal but would  $view = views_get_view('views_name');
  $view->execute();
  print $view->render();

Comment: work in the same way

Comment: @user3111148 see the FourKitchens article, the block needs another function to show up in the blocks admin ui (hook_block_info). for what you asked you need to get the 2 view "results" and merge them into 1 array and show the top 3. My code does that -- views_get_view doesnt do that as you have in your code above.

Comment: Hi Tenken ,I have fixed the issues I had previously.Thanks for your help. The one issue I having is that results from upcoming events are not displaying (there is one of each type) I have printed $upcoming_events and it displays the right information.

Comment: hmm i'm not sure at the moment. use `print_r` or the devel module to see the array content you're printing out.

Comment: hi tenken , how would I add more fields to the output

Comment: fields are returned per whole row in the results. you would edit the View and simply add more fields as needed .... ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to create this in views will be to just manually read it and re-create using the views UI.